# Flutter text is not wrapping inside Row

Tags: flutter, dart, text, row

I have a simple `Widget` with a `Row` and `Text` inside of it. If the `Text` is longer it should simply go in the next line but right now it is staying in one line and giving me an `overflow`:

[image]

This is my code for it:

```
class HintKeyPoint extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const HintKeyPoint({
    required this.text,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: scaleWidth(10),
        ),
        Container(
          height: scaleWidth(16),
          width: scaleWidth(16),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.primaryLight, shape: BoxShape.circle),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: scaleWidth(10),
        ),
        Text(
          text,
          style: AppTextStyles.h7,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Why is the `Text` not taking the vertical space? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap Text widget with Expanded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `Text Widget` with `Expanded Widget`.

Example:

```
Expanded(
    child: Text(
    "lorem10 lorem10 lorem10lorem10lorem10lorem10lorem10 lorem10lorem10lorem10lorem10lorem10 lorem10lorem10lorem10lorem10lorem10 lorem10",
    ),
),
```

Comment: thanks :) Alex was first so I give him the correct answer but yours is the same, so thanks for your help

Comment: That's Ok :) I only Added code , cause some asker don't get it and prefer to copy/paste